# How to authenticate (login / logout) in RESTful web application in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I would like to authenticate with

```
http://myhost/login?user=...&password=...
```

and logout with

```
http://myhost/logout
```

I am using Gradle, Spring Boot and Java config, so no web.xml, no context configurations, no web forms and so on.

Can't escape from google noise on multipage and multifile samples...

Comment: Do you want users to login into your service? Then it would not be truly Restful as it will have to keep state of user authentication...

Comment: Why? As I know, login data is usually kept in cookies etc, i.e. it transferred each time in each request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [using a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526384/java-servlet-and-authentication)? Seems like what you want to do for passing the username and password as http parameters. Otherwise, you might also consider [HTTP BASIC authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient). It passes the username and password in the http headers using base64 "encryption". Of course, complete website security is a different discussion.

See this [example of using HTTP BASIC authentication](https://github.com/karlnicholas/dukes-forest/tree/master/dukes-payment).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using tokens.

The login service would accept the credentials, generate a token (a UUID type 4 for example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), store the token in a table and return it.

In every call, the client would have to send the token in the header or as another parameter, so a filter or something would check it to allow access.

On logout, the token would be deleted (you may want to have a process that deletes the tokens after a certain amount of time or something like that).