# How to preprocess all requests in Spring Web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a `RESTful` Spring application, which can process various request with various controllers and various `@RequestMapping`-s.

Now I wish each request contain additionally a user/password pair, user as user `GET` parameter `?user=username` and password in password `POST` parameter.

Is it possible to "preprocess" all requests before they go to controllers and check credentials and possible return authentication error?

Is this a mechanism, which is caller "filters" or not?

Comment: it could be better if you choose Spring-securityas well Spring-MVC in your case.

Comment: This mechanism is called "interceptors" in Spring MVC

Comment: @vishalgajera how to keep RESTful with Spring Security? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453693/how-to-authenticate-login-logout-in-restful-web-application-in-spring

Comment: Did you try implementing HandlerInterceptor?

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of ways for intercepting the requests before they land into controllers.

> 1. Using Servlet Filters:

```
    @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "path-to-intercept", filterName = "your-filter-name")
    public class MyRequestFilter implements Filter {
        init(...);
        doFilter(...);
        destroy(); 
    }
```

> 2. Using Spring HandlerIntecptors:

```
    public class MyRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

        preHandle(...); //called before the request lands to the controller.
        postHandle(...); //called after the controller method finishes execution.
        afterCompletion(...); //called before the response is sent.
    }
```

And in your configuration:

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/yourInterceptingPath/" />
            <bean class="path-to-your-Interceptor.MyRequestInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: In your servlet configuration file.

Comment: I don't have one and don't wish to create one :)

Comment: How is your request being handled then?

Comment: servlet 3.0 allows no `web.xml`

Comment: True. But in order to process the requests in Spring MVC, you have to register the Dispatcher Servlet. In this case, you can use option 1.